# TypeScript: Create a more restrictive type from an existing type

Tags: typescript

I have a library that defines a class, say, as:

```js
class Foo{
    foo: 'a' | 'b';
    bar: string;

    // ...
};
```

Because of my implementation, I know that when I do a query, `foo: 'a'` always. If it were not it would be an error. So I am trying to define a type that enforces this:

```js
type FooA = Foo & {
    foo: 'a',
    bar: string
}
```

This does not seem to work, and the type of `foo` is set to `never`.

How can I restrict the type like this?

Comment: [LGTM](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLUBmCBcUA5AIZFQA+xARkQDSbbUkBOhAzsCwJYB2A5ugC+AbnTpQkWAgCCyaYgBkaRljxxCpesPEBjOL064EJQvDhyUGNQWJkGWZmzvscJdgBMcRHen2HgYzhqM1l5ayDNWjooAHpYqAAVcGgiACJqNPJudiheOED3dm5+XhJqABtoYERJVLSSLMYnTXc3T29hIA)

Comment: yep, your code work.. where are you seeing the error?

Comment: @DamianGreen My bad, turns out the API actually uses a class (which I didn't notice). Let me update the post.

Comment: It still works with a class. 
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oAcCuAjEAlsNMPAHYQAuATtsJfNQBQCUK6G0lAFgRAHQAzRNAC80AERgJAbg4YeffrjDUxkldVkcAvqg7D4ALmgByMKYA+p3KbkZNJqtQJkA5nJ1zUlAJ6YAUzhEAEF1BCQAMnZOaEMTc1MAGnloR2hnVzdUPVRSCko40JMIsPE0DHizCxSHVRMJTQkU3PyqIvgAIRLQ9QqOhNtatPqzTWScoA)
Can you provide more context to your code because I think there is something else going on that your code doesn't work as expected.